# Nodejs pino logger. none json output

Tags: node.js, logging

I would like to use pino as logger on my nodejs application becouse i understand it has the best preformence.
I need the log to be in the following format:
19.2.2019 22:50:21 ERROR MyHostName message = { action: http, data: myData ..... }

But pino log only JSON format.
I read about pino-pretty. But it look too complex to achive for simple task.

Someone use pino to log as plan text and json?
Do you have any other recommend logger libraries?

Answer (score 0):

```
  const logger = require('pino')({
    level: process.env.LOG_LEVEL,
    prettyPrint: true
 });
```

> [2021-04-28T07:04:25.113Z] DEBUG (15 on f7baba7a14ab): Received event

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/pinojs/pino-toke to format the message as you want. Useful for things like CloudWatch to prevent multiline logging.

Answer (score -2):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-node-logger to log as plan text and json